# r - how to change position of rows according to their rank

Tags: r

This is an exemplary piece of code:

```
df<-data.frame(c(14, 37, 15, 18, 1, 7))
df$rankk=rank(-df)
```

and this is the result:

```
    Rank
14   4
37   1
15   3
18   2
 1   6
 7   5
```

Now I want something like the rows position also changes according to their ranks.
Desired:

```
37   1
18   2
15   3
14   4
 7   5
 1   6
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need `rank`? You can simply use `sort`.

Comment: Brendan Answer worked acc to my need. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R you're looking for `order`

```
df <- df[order(df$rankk), ]
```

In the tidyverse world you'd use `arrange`:

```
df %<>%
   arrange(rankk)
```

Or better yet skip creating the rank column at all,

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(14, 37, 15, 18, 1, 7))
# base R version
df <- df[order(-df$x), ]
# tidyverse version
df %<>%
   arrange(desc(x))
```